# R: How to find the maximal index for which an entry in a vector meets a certain condition

Tags: r, vector

I have a vector X which can potentially contain a very large number of entries and I want to find the maximal index i such that X[i] <= a*i/m (for some constants a,m) and I'd really rather not loop over the vector. I thought about using Position but I can't figure out how to make a suitable function that would take into account the indexes of the vector.

I forgot to mention that the entries of the vector will be sorted so that might help.

Help would be appreciated

Comment: You are much more likely to receive a helpful answer if you provide a [**minimal, reproducible example**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) including input data, the desired result, and the code you have tried and why it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I interpret your question (as of "right now" ) differently from ChinmayP, so maybe this:

```
foo <- which ( X/(1:(length(X)) < a/m)

rev(foo)[1]
```

That will give you the element of `X` with the largest index `i` (as in `X[i]` ) which meets your condition.

Answer (score 1):

Following should give you what you want.

```
max(which(X <= a/m * seq_along(X)))
```

Looping backwards might still be better idea though, as you only want maximum index value.

```
for ( i in length(X):1 ) { if (X[i] <= a*i/m) break } ;  i
```

When the loop breaks, i will contain your required max index.